Moengage user push notifications enabled or not?
I want to know if there's any api in moengage by which I can get if user has enabled push notifications or not, I want to keep my systems in sync to know for which users push notifications is enabled or not.
I read all the documentation and also checked user apis from where I fetch user data but didn't found anything specific by which I can get if user notifications are enabled or not.

You can use the Platform API(Android/iOS) to check if the user has granted the push permission.
The MoEngage SDK also queries the Platform to get the status.
